# SQLite reveals floating point when sum is subtracted from same total amount in literal

Tags: sqlite

I have a table that have `amount` column. When add up, the sum looks normal. But when it is subtracted from the same total in literal, there's a floating point.

Consider this sample case:

```
create table a(
    id number,
    amount number(9,2),
    constraint a_pk primary key (id)
);

insert into a values(1006118,1083.33);
insert into a values(1006123,614.29);
insert into a values(1006124,783.33);
insert into a values(1006096,783.33);
insert into a values(1006104,833.33);
insert into a values(1006115,533.33);
insert into a values(1006116,633.33);
insert into a values(1006092,683.33);
```

The sum of the amount is 5947.6. The difference `5947.6-sum(amount)` should be zero but SQLite returns 9.09494701772928e-13.

```
select sum(amount), 5947.6-sum(amount) difference
from a;
```

It's as if there's a missing value. Or am I missing something?

Comment: or that sqlite assumes that those decimals are repeating?

Comment: You might be interested in https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity_name_examples (and in https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid considering your primary key definition)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SQLite cheats on data types](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html). Unlike other databases, it ignores your declared column type and guesses the type based on what you're inserting. `number` is not a valid SQL type, but SQLite doesn't care.

[Floating point numbers are only an approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Accuracy_problems) and will accumulate errors if you do math on them. This is a general problem with floating point numbers. SQLite will turn `1083.33` into a floating point number.

What you need is an [arbitrary precision numeric data type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) like `decimal` or `numeric`. Unfortunately SQLite does not have these.

You can mitigate the problem by rounding.

```
select
  sum(amount),
  round(5947.6-sum(amount), 2) difference
from a;
```

But this is not 100% accurate as errors will still accumulate, you'll just lop them off at the end. If you want accuracy, store everything in integers and shift their values over two decimal places.

```
sqlite> insert into a values(1006118,108333);
sqlite> insert into a values(1006123,61429);
sqlite> insert into a values(1006124,78333);
sqlite> insert into a values(1006096,78333);
sqlite> insert into a values(1006104,83333);
sqlite> insert into a values(1006115,53333);
sqlite> insert into a values(1006116,63333);
sqlite> insert into a values(1006092,68333);
sqlite> select sum(amount), 594760-sum(amount) difference from a;
sum(amount)  difference
-----------  ----------
594760       0
```

Answer (score 2):

Digital computer floating point arithmetic is inexact.  Some decimal numbers cannot be represented exactly as floating point numbers, so when you ask for the sum of some inexactly representable numbers the result isn't internally represented as an exact decimal number, and so when you subtract what you think is the exact decimal result you don't end up with zero.

Normally such inexactness can be hidden with careful rounding:

```
select round(sum(amount),2), 5947.6-round(sum(amount),2) difference from a;
```

See [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)