# Sqlite Returning Random SUM value

Tags: sqlite

I have an SQLite database, with 3 different tables.  Trying to get a sum value of them (well actually, the sum of one table, less the combined total of the other two).  This is the SQL Statement:

```
SELECT SUM(amount) FROM 
(       
  SELECT coalesce(SUM(amount * -1), 0.0) as amount
  FROM instalments
  WHERE category_id = 7
  UNION ALL
  SELECT coalesce(SUM(amount), 0.0) as amount
  FROM transactions
  WHERE category_id = 7 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT coalesce(SUM(amount), 0.0) as amount
  FROM pending_transactions
  WHERE category_id = 7 
)
```

The first statment:

```
SELECT coalesce(SUM(amount * -1), 0.0) as amount
FROM transactions
WHERE category_id = 7
```

returns: `amount -15811.54`

Second statement:

```
SELECT coalesce(SUM(amount), 0.0) as amount
FROM pending_transactions
WHERE category_id = 7
```

Returns: `amount 0.0`

And the third:

```
SELECT coalesce(SUM(amount), 0.0) as amount
FROM transactions
WHERE category_id = 7
```

returns: `amount 15811.54`

But, when I run the whole thing, I get:

```
SUM(amount)
1.81898940354586e-12
```

What could possibly be causing this???

Database definitions for all 3 on the amount column are:
`"amount"   numeric NOT NULL`

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60678037/sqlite-reveals-floating-point-when-sum-is-subtracted-from-same-total-amount-in-l

Comment: Thanks @forpas I think the safest way might be to do the math outside of the SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the post @forpas shared in the comments.  Adding a ROUND(SUM(blah), 2) fixed the issue for me.